Downloading .yaml file to esp32 via ESPhome in Docker container
I am trying to download .yaml configuratoin file to ESP32 DEVKITV1. I am downloading via ESPhome which is in a Docker container located on linux debian machine. When I start downloading with command sudo docker-compose exec esphome esphome run /config/mitsubishi_heatpump.yaml or from browser interface (mitsubishi_heatpump.yaml >> Install >> Plug into this computer), I get this error:
INFO ESPHome 2024.7.3
INFO Reading configuration /config/mitsubishi_heatpump.yaml...
INFO Detected timezone 'Etc/UTC'
INFO Generating C++ source...
INFO Compiling app...
Processing mitsubishi (board: esp32doit-devkit-v1; framework: arduino; platform: platformio/espressif32@5.4.0)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 8.4.0+2021r2-patch5
Dependency Graph
|-- AsyncTCP-esphome @ 2.1.3
|-- WiFi @ 2.0.0
|-- FS @ 2.0.0
|-- Update @ 2.0.0
|-- ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome @ 3.2.2
|-- DNSServer @ 2.0.0
|-- ESPmDNS @ 2.0.0
|-- noise-c @ 0.1.4
|-- ArduinoJson @ 6.18.5
|-- HeatPump @ 1.0.0+sha.5d1e146
Compiling .pioenvs/mitsubishi/src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp.o
Compiling .pioenvs/mitsubishi/src/main.cpp.o
Compiling .pioenvs/mitsubishi/lib789/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o
Compiling .pioenvs/mitsubishi/lib789/WiFi/WiFiSTA.cpp.o
In file included from src/esphome.h:29,
                 from src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:20,
                 from src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:21:
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:182:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_operating_timeout_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:182:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_operating_timeout_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:183:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_idle_timeout_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:183:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_idle_timeout_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:184:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_ping_timeout_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:184:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_ping_timeout_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:185:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:185:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:186:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_ping_request_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:186:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_ping_request_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp: In member function 'virtual void MitsubishiHeatPump::control(const esphome::climate::ClimateCall&)':
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:252:9: error: 'last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_' was not declared in this scope
     if (last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_.has_value()) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:252:9: note: suggested alternative: 'enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout'
     if (last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_.has_value()) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp: In member function 'void MitsubishiHeatPump::set_remote_temperature(float)':
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:625:9: error: 'last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_' was not declared in this scope
         last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_ =
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:625:9: note: suggested alternative: 'enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout'
         last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_ =
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:628:9: error: 'last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_' was not declared in this scope
         last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_.reset();
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:628:9: note: suggested alternative: 'enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout'
         last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_.reset();
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp: In member function 'void MitsubishiHeatPump::ping()':
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:636:5: error: 'last_ping_request_' was not declared in this scope
     last_ping_request_ = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp: In member function 'void MitsubishiHeatPump::set_remote_operating_timeout_minutes(int)':
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:641:5: error: 'remote_operating_timeout_' was not declared in this scope
     remote_operating_timeout_ = std::chrono::minutes(minutes);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:641:5: note: suggested alternative: 'set_remote_operating_timeout_minutes'
     remote_operating_timeout_ = std::chrono::minutes(minutes);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     set_remote_operating_timeout_minutes
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp: In member function 'void MitsubishiHeatPump::set_remote_idle_timeout_minutes(int)':
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:646:5: error: 'remote_idle_timeout_' was not declared in this scope
     remote_idle_timeout_ = std::chrono::minutes(minutes);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:646:5: note: suggested alternative: 'set_timeout'
     remote_idle_timeout_ = std::chrono::minutes(minutes);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     set_timeout
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp: In member function 'void MitsubishiHeatPump::set_remote_ping_timeout_minutes(int)':
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:651:5: error: 'remote_ping_timeout_' was not declared in this scope
     remote_ping_timeout_ = std::chrono::minutes(minutes);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:651:5: note: suggested alternative: 'set_timeout'
     remote_ping_timeout_ = std::chrono::minutes(minutes);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     set_timeout
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp: In member function 'void MitsubishiHeatPump::enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout()':
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:656:9: error: 'remote_ping_timeout_' was not declared in this scope
     if (remote_ping_timeout_.has_value() && last_ping_request_.has_value()) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:656:9: note: suggested alternative: 'set_timeout'
     if (remote_ping_timeout_.has_value() && last_ping_request_.has_value()) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         set_timeout
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:656:45: error: 'last_ping_request_' was not declared in this scope
     if (remote_ping_timeout_.has_value() && last_ping_request_.has_value()) {
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:669:28: error: 'remote_operating_timeout_' was not declared in this scope
         this->operating_ ? remote_operating_timeout_ : remote_idle_timeout_;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/esphome.h:29,
                 from src/main.cpp:3:
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:182:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_operating_timeout_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:182:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_operating_timeout_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:183:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_idle_timeout_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:183:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_idle_timeout_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:184:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_ping_timeout_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:184:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<60>>> remote_ping_timeout_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:185:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:185:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_;
         ^~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:186:14: error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_ping_request_;
              ^~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.h:186:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards
         std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> last_ping_request_;
         ^~~
Compiling .pioenvs/mitsubishi/lib789/WiFi/WiFiScan.cpp.o
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:669:28: note: suggested alternative: 'set_remote_operating_timeout_minutes'
         this->operating_ ? remote_operating_timeout_ : remote_idle_timeout_;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            set_remote_operating_timeout_minutes
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:669:56: error: 'remote_idle_timeout_' was not declared in this scope
         this->operating_ ? remote_operating_timeout_ : remote_idle_timeout_;
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:669:56: note: suggested alternative: 'set_timeout'
         this->operating_ ? remote_operating_timeout_ : remote_idle_timeout_;
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                        set_timeout
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:671:13: error: 'last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_' was not declared in this scope
             last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_.has_value()) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp:671:13: note: suggested alternative: 'enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout'
             last_remote_temperature_sensor_update_.has_value()) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             enforce_remote_temperature_sensor_timeout
Compiling .pioenvs/mitsubishi/lib789/WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp.o
*** [.pioenvs/mitsubishi/src/esphome/components/mitsubishi_heatpump/espmhp.cpp.o] Error 1
*** [.pioenvs/mitsubishi/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1

My .yaml includes board and platform names.
esphome:
  name: ${name}
  platform: esp32
  board: esp32doit-devkit-v1

Container is configured as:
  esphome:
    container_name: esphome
    image: esphome/esphome:latest
    volumes:
      - ./esphome:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host

I don't have slightest idea what the error means so I kindly ask for help.

I'm confused by what's going on. Can you clarify more by what "download .yaml configuratoin file to ESP32 DEVKITV1" means and what you expect that docker-compose ... command to do? How are the devkit and the docker container connected? From the console output, I'm seeing esphome generates C++ code that isn't compatible with the compiler options its using.

On second thought see this thread: https://github.com/geoffdavis/esphome-mitsubishiheatpump/issues/152  looks like the fix for your exact problem with the mitsubishi_heatpump project

Thank you, docker-compose exec is to execute commands from inside of container because my ESPhome is located inside of container. Github thread is discussing UART error which my error has nothing to do with.

You don't "download the .yaml file to an ESP32". ESPHome uses the YAML file to describe the application; it then generates the code for that application and compiles it. The errors mean exactly what they say - as @GandhiGandhi pointed out - the code in the "mitsubishi_heatpump" component uses C++ features that aren't available in the version of the compiler that ESPHome is using. You need to either rewrite that component to be compatible with the compiler or update ESPHome and the copy of PlatformIO it uses to use the newer compiler.

The key line I'm seeing in your error that links to the github thread is "82:9: note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards" -- I'm looking at the compiler output not the UART error. Try the solution here: https://github.com/geoffdavis/esphome-mitsubishiheatpump/issues/152#issuecomment-2186021588

I have the problem solved. link this solution helped, I copied there described platforio_options to .yaml and it compiled successfully. Thank you.
